# Chess engine for chess without checks in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, chess, sdl

### Project Description:

*Chess without checks: A chess variant where you can take the enemy king.*

This engine implementation is for chess without checks. Since checks don't exist, expect the code to not account for pinned pieces. Kings can move to dangerous squares (and be captured next turn). Castling is not implemented yet.

The project is comprised of 3 `.cpp` and 3 `.h` files, and `main.cpp`

Most of the action happens in `board.cpp`, which is the one I needed review for the most.

---

### File explanation:

`graphics.cpp` uses SDL2 library to draw the window, board and pieces, and handle events.

`fen.cpp` declares the `Type` and `Color` enums for the pieces, and loads [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) codes into the board.
The board is an array of 64 ints. `Color` and `Type` int values are combined to create an int that represents a piece.

`board.cpp` handles everything that happens on the board. When the user plays a move, it calculates a response with `PlayComputerMove()` which in turn uses `Minimax(int(&board)[64], int depth, bool isMaximizing)` to find the best move. I have big performance issues here.

`Evaluate(int(&board)[64])` evaluates the position. Note that it only counts material. The computer doesn't understand strategy, so when no obvious moves exist (taking a piece, protecting a piece) it just moves pieces back and forth, which is to be expected.

---

### Concerns:

**1. Performance:**
Even at a depth of 3, the algorithm seems to be taking multiple seconds to finish. You may notice `std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli> total;` which counts the milliseconds that `GetLegalMoves(int position)` took to execute (in sum for all the times it was called) each move. In my system, it seems to take ~1000ms, and `PlayComputerMove()` takes about 5-6 thousand ms.

**2. Design:**
Currently, the algorithm searches the board for the black/white pieces in a for loop. I could use a `std::map` to keep track of the pieces at all times, but I believe it wouldn't positively impact performance by a lot.

`GetLegalMoves(int position)` returns a `std::list<int>*`. This works, but it seems ugly to me. I do delete it after I don't need the list anymore. Returning a reference to a list seems to throw exceptions. I am only doing this to avoid copying the list.

Comments on bad practices and bad style in my code are also greatly appreciated.

**Note:** Implementing strategy (accounting for doubled pawns, center control, pawns close to promotion) is not my priority for now.

---

### Code:

`graphics.h`

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "board.h"
#include "SDL.h"

#define SCREEN_X 0
#define SCREEN_Y 0
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 640
#define SQUARE_SIZE 64

class Graphics {
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)> window;
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, decltype(&SDL_DestroyRenderer)> renderer;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    SDL_Texture* boardTexture;
    SDL_Texture* piecesTexture;
    Board* board;
    SDL_Event ev;
    int mouse_x, mouse_y;
    bool Init();
    void InitBoard();
    void InitSpritesheet();
    void FillPiece(int piece, int xx, int yy);
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();
    void PreRender();
    void Render();
    void UpdatePieces();
    void LimitFPS();
    bool InputCheck();
    void SetBoard(Board* board);
};
#endif
```

`graphics.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graphics.h"

Graphics::Graphics() : window(nullptr, SDL_DestroyWindow), renderer(nullptr, SDL_DestroyRenderer) {
    Init();
    InitBoard();
    InitSpritesheet();
}

Graphics::~Graphics() {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(boardTexture);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Graphics::PreRender() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer.get());
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer.get(), boardTexture, 0, 0);
}


bool Graphics::Init(){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "SDL failed to initialize. Error:" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        window.reset(SDL_CreateWindow("Chess AI", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));
        renderer.reset(SDL_CreateRenderer(window.get(), -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED));
        return true;
    }
}

void Graphics::InitBoard() {
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = SCREEN_X;
    r.y = SCREEN_Y;
    r.w = SQUARE_SIZE;
    r.h = SQUARE_SIZE;
    SDL_Surface* surf = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window.get());
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
            SDL_FillRect(surf, &r, 0xAFC3C7FF);
            r.x += SQUARE_SIZE * 2;
        }
        r.y += SQUARE_SIZE;
        r.x = (r.x == SQUARE_SIZE * 9 ? 0 : SQUARE_SIZE);
    }
    r.y = SCREEN_Y;
    r.x = SQUARE_SIZE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
            SDL_FillRect(surf, &r, 0x618187FF);
            r.x += SQUARE_SIZE * 2;
        }
        r.y += SQUARE_SIZE;
        r.x = (r.x == SQUARE_SIZE * 9 ? 0 : SQUARE_SIZE);
    }
    boardTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer.get(), surf);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
}

void Graphics::InitSpritesheet() {
    SDL_Surface* surf = SDL_LoadBMP("pieces.bmp");
    if (surf == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to load spritesheet. Error:" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    piecesTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer.get(), surf);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
}

void Graphics::LimitFPS()
{
    a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> work_time = a - b;

    if (work_time.count() < 16.75) {
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta_ms(16.75 - work_time.count());
        auto delta_ms_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delta_ms);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delta_ms_duration.count()));
    }

    b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> sleep_time = b - a;
}

bool Graphics::InputCheck() {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0) {
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);
        switch(ev.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                return true;
            break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                int index = ((mouse_x - SCREEN_X) / SQUARE_SIZE) % 8 + ((mouse_y - SCREEN_Y) / SQUARE_SIZE) * 8;
                board->Click(index);
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Graphics::SetBoard(Board* board) {
    Graphics::board = board;
}

void Graphics::Render() {
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer.get());
}

void Graphics::FillPiece(int piece, int xx, int yy) {
    Type t = GetType(piece);
    int y = (GetColor(piece) == Color::White ? 0 : SQUARE_SIZE);
    int x = 0;
    switch (t) {
    case Type::King:
        x = 0;
        break;
    case Type::Queen:
        x = SQUARE_SIZE;
        break;
    case Type::Bishop:
        x = 2 * SQUARE_SIZE;
        break;
    case Type::Knight:
        x = 3 * SQUARE_SIZE;
        break;
    case Type::Rook:
        x = 4 * SQUARE_SIZE;
        break;
    case Type::Pawn:
        x = 5 * SQUARE_SIZE;
        break;
    }
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    SDL_Rect dstRect;
    srcRect.x = x;
    srcRect.y = y;
    srcRect.w = SQUARE_SIZE;
    srcRect.h = SQUARE_SIZE;
    dstRect.x = xx;
    dstRect.y = yy;
    dstRect.w = SQUARE_SIZE;
    dstRect.h = SQUARE_SIZE;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer.get(), piecesTexture, &srcRect, &dstRect);
}

void Graphics::UpdatePieces() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        int piece = board->GetPiece(i);
        if (piece != 0) {
            FillPiece(piece, (i % 8) * SQUARE_SIZE, (i >> 3) * SQUARE_SIZE);
        }
    }
    int heldPiece = board->GetHeldPiece();
    if (heldPiece != 0) {
        FillPiece(heldPiece, mouse_x - SQUARE_SIZE / 2, mouse_y - SQUARE_SIZE / 2);
    }
}
```

`fen.h`

```
#ifndef FEN_H
#define FEN_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

enum class Type {
    Pawn = 1,
    Knight = 2,
    Bishop = 4,
    Rook = 8,
    Queen = 16,
    King = 32
};

enum class Color {
    Black = 64,
    White = 128
};

inline Type GetType(int piece) {
    return static_cast<Type>(piece & 0x3F);
}

inline Color GetColor(int piece) {
    return static_cast<Color>((piece >> 6) << 6);
}

struct FEN {
    std::string piecePlacement;
    Color activeColor;
    bool whiteCanCastleKingside;
    bool whiteCanCastleQueenside;
    bool blackCanCastleKingside;
    bool blackCanCastleQueenside;
    int enPassantSquare;
    bool justMovedTwoSquares;
    int halfmoveClock;
    int fullmoveNumber;
    int blackKingPos;
    int whiteKingPos;

    FEN(int (&board)[64], std::string& str);
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const FEN& fen) {
    out << "FEN: {\n"
        << fen.piecePlacement << ", \n"
        << ((fen.activeColor == Color::White) ? "White to play" : "Black to play") << ", \n"
        << "Move: " << fen.fullmoveNumber << "\n"
        << "}"
        << std::endl;
    return out;
}
#endif
```

`fen.cpp`

```
#include "fen.h"

// Syntactic sugar
int operator|(const Type& T, const Color& C) {
    return static_cast<int>(T) | static_cast<int>(C);
}

bool operator&(int I, Type T) {
    return I & static_cast<int>(T);
}

bool operator&(int I, Color C) {
    return I & static_cast<int>(C);
}

template <typename Out>
void split(const std::string& s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(iss, item, delim)) {
        *result++ = item;
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
};

FEN::FEN(int(&board)[64], std::string& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> fenParts = split(str, ' ');
    piecePlacement = fenParts[0];

    int i = 0;
    for (char c : piecePlacement) {
        if (c != '/') {
            if (c >= '1' && c <= '8') {
                i += c - '0';
            }
            else {
                if (isupper(c)) {
                    board[i] += (int)Color::White;
                }
                else {
                    board[i] += (int)Color::Black;
                }
                switch (tolower(c)) {
                case 'p':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::Pawn;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::Knight;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::Bishop;
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::Rook;
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::Queen;
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    board[i] += (int)Type::King;
                    if (board[i] & Color::White) {
                        whiteKingPos = i;
                    }
                    else {
                        blackKingPos = i;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    activeColor = (fenParts[1])[0] == 'w' ? Color::White : Color::Black;

    for (char c : fenParts[2]) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'K':
            whiteCanCastleKingside = true;
            break;
        case 'Q':
            whiteCanCastleQueenside = true;
            break;
        case 'k':
            blackCanCastleKingside = true;
            break;
        case 'q':
            blackCanCastleQueenside = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ((fenParts[3])[0] != '-') {
        int letter = (fenParts[3])[0] - 'a';
        int number = (fenParts[3])[0] - '0' * 8;
        enPassantSquare = letter + number;
    }

    halfmoveClock = std::stoi(fenParts[4]);
    fullmoveNumber = std::stoi(fenParts[5]);
}
```

`board.h`

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include "fen.h"


class Board {
    int board[64];
    std::unique_ptr<FEN> fen;
    std::list<int>* heldLegalMoves;
    int legalMoveCounter = 0;

    std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli> total;

    int heldPiece, heldSquare = -1;
    bool toMove = true;
    bool justMovedTwoSquares = false;

    void PlayComputerMove();
    int Evaluate(int(&board)[64]);
    int Minimax(int(&board)[64], int depth, bool isMaximizing);

public:
    Board(std::string& fenCode);
    std::list<int>* GetLegalMoves(int position);
    
    void Click(int index);
    void UndoClick();
    const int GetPiece(int index) const;
    int GetHeldPiece();
};
#endif
```

`board.cpp`

```
#include "board.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

Board::Board(std::string& fenCode) {
    fen = std::make_unique<FEN>(board, fenCode);
}

std::list<int>* Board::GetLegalMoves(int position) {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::list<int>* ret = new std::list<int>;
    int piece = board[position];
    Type t = GetType(piece);
    Color c = GetColor(piece);
    Color e = ((c == Color::White) ? Color::Black : Color::White);
    switch (t) {
        case Type::Pawn:
        {
            if (c == Color::White) {
                if (position >= 8) {
                    if (position >= 48 && position <= 55 && board[position - 16] == 0 && board[position - 8] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(position - 16);
                        fen->enPassantSquare = position - 8;
                        justMovedTwoSquares = true;
                    }
                    if (board[position - 8] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(position - 8);
                    }
                    if ((position % 8 != 0 && GetColor(board[position - 9]) == e) || fen->enPassantSquare == position - 9) {
                        ret->push_back(position - 9);
                    }
                    if ((position + 1) % 8 != 0 && GetColor(board[position - 7]) == e || fen->enPassantSquare == position - 7) {
                        ret->push_back(position - 7);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (position <= 55) {
                    if (position >= 8 && position <= 15 && board[position + 16] == 0 && board[position + 8] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(position + 16);
                        fen->enPassantSquare = position + 8;
                        justMovedTwoSquares = true;
                    }
                    if (board[position + 8] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(position + 8);
                    }
                    if ((position % 8 != 0 && GetColor(board[position + 7]) == e) || fen->enPassantSquare == position + 7) {
                        ret->push_back(position + 7);
                    }
                    if (((position + 1) % 8 != 0 && GetColor(board[position + 9]) == e) || fen->enPassantSquare == position + 9) {
                        ret->push_back(position + 9);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case Type::Knight:
        {
            if (position >= 16 && position % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position - 17]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position - 17);
                }
            }
            if (position >= 16 && (position + 1) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position - 15]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position - 15);
                }
            }
            if (position >= 8 && position % 8 != 0 && (position - 1) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position - 10]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position - 10);
                }
            }
            if (position >= 8 && (position + 1) % 8 != 0 && (position + 2) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position - 6]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position - 6);
                }
            }
            if (position <= 47 && (position + 1) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position + 17]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position + 17);
                }
            }
            if (position <= 47 && position % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position + 15]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position + 15);
                }
            }
            if (position <= 55 && (position + 1) % 8 != 0 && (position + 2) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position + 10]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position + 10);
                }
            }
            if (position <= 55 && position % 8 != 0 && (position - 1) % 8 != 0) {
                if (GetColor(board[position + 6]) != c) {
                    ret->push_back(position + 6);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case Type::Bishop:
        {
            int pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 9 && (pTemp % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp -= 9;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 8 && ((pTemp + 1) % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp -= 7;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 && (pTemp % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp += 7;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 && ((pTemp + 1) % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp += 9;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            break;
        }
        case Type::Rook:
        {
            int pTemp = position;
            while (((pTemp--)) % 8 != 0) {
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while ((++pTemp) % 8 != 0) {
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 8) {
                pTemp -= 8;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 != 0) {
                pTemp += 8;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            break;
        }
        case Type::Queen:
        {
            int pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 9 && (pTemp % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp -= 9;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 8 && ((pTemp + 1) % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp -= 7;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 && (pTemp % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp += 7;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 && ((pTemp + 1) % 8 != 0)) {
                pTemp += 9;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);
                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (((pTemp--)) % 8 != 0) {
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while ((++pTemp) % 8 != 0) {
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp >= 8) {
                pTemp -= 8;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }
            pTemp = position;
            while (pTemp <= 55 != 0) {
                pTemp += 8;
                if (board[pTemp] != 0) {
                    if (GetColor(board[pTemp]) == e)
                        ret->push_back(pTemp);

                    break;
                }
                ret->push_back(pTemp);
            }

            break;
        }
        case Type::King:
        {
            if (c == Color::White) {
                if (position == 60) {
                    if (fen->whiteCanCastleKingside && board[62] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(62);
                    }
                    if (fen->whiteCanCastleQueenside && board[58] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(58);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (position == 4) {
                    if (fen->blackCanCastleKingside && board[6] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(6);
                    }
                    if (fen->blackCanCastleQueenside && board[2] == 0) {
                        ret->push_back(2);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (position % 8 != 0) {
                if (position >= 9) {
                    if (GetColor(board[position - 9]) != c)
                        ret->push_back(position - 9);
                }

                if (GetColor(board[position - 1]) != c)
                    ret->push_back(position - 1);

                if (position <= 55) {
                    if (GetColor(board[position + 7]) != c)
                        ret->push_back(position + 7);
                }
            }
            if ((position + 1) % 8 != 0) {
                if (position >= 7) {
                    if (GetColor(board[position - 7]) != c)
                        ret->push_back(position - 7);
                }

                if (GetColor(board[position + 1]) != c)
                    ret->push_back(position + 1);

                if (position < 55) {
                    if (GetColor(board[position + 9]) != c)
                        ret->push_back(position + 9);
                }
            }
            if (position >= 8) {
                if (GetColor(board[position - 8]) != c)
                    ret->push_back(position - 8);
            }
            if (position <= 55) {
                if (GetColor(board[position + 8]) != c)
                    ret->push_back(position + 8);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    total += t2 - t1;
    legalMoveCounter += ret->size();
    return ret;
}

int Board::Evaluate(int(&board)[64]) {
    int eval = 0;
    int whiteBishopCount = 0;
    int blackBishopCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        int piece = board[i];
        if (piece != 0) {
            int sign = GetColor(piece) == Color::White ? -1 : 1;
            Color c = GetColor(piece);
            Type t = GetType(piece);
            switch (t) {
                case Type::Pawn: {
                    eval += 10 * sign;
                    break;
                }
                case Type::Knight: {
                    eval += 30 * sign;
                    break;
                }
                case Type::Bishop: {
                    if (c == Color::White) {
                        whiteBishopCount++;
                        if (whiteBishopCount > 1) {
                            eval += 5;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        blackBishopCount++;
                        if (blackBishopCount > 1) {
                            eval -= 5;
                        }
                    }
                    eval += 30 * sign;
                    break;
                }
                case Type::Rook: {
                    eval += 40 * sign;
                    break;
                }
                case Type::Queen: {
                    eval += 90 * sign;
                    break;
                }
                case Type::King: {
                    eval += INT16_MAX * sign;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return eval;
}

void Board::Click(int index) {
    if (heldSquare == index) {
        UndoClick();
        return;
    }
    if (heldPiece == 0) {
        if (toMove) {
            delete heldLegalMoves;
            heldPiece = board[index];
            heldLegalMoves = GetLegalMoves(index);
            board[index] = 0;
            heldSquare = index;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (std::find(heldLegalMoves->begin(), heldLegalMoves->end(), index) != heldLegalMoves->end()) {
            if (index == fen->enPassantSquare && GetType(heldPiece) == Type::Pawn) {
                if (fen->enPassantSquare < 32) {
                    board[index + 8] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    board[index - 8] = 0;
                }
            }
            board[index] = heldPiece;
            heldPiece = 0;
            heldSquare = -1;
            toMove = false;
            PlayComputerMove();
            if (!justMovedTwoSquares) {
                fen->enPassantSquare = 0;
            }
            else {
                justMovedTwoSquares = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            UndoClick();
        }
    }
}

void Board::UndoClick() {
    if (heldPiece != 0) {
        board[heldSquare] = heldPiece;
        heldPiece = 0;
        heldSquare = -1;
    }
}

void Board::PlayComputerMove() {
    std::vector<int> blackPieces;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (board[i] != 0 && GetColor(board[i]) == Color::Black) {
            blackPieces.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    int bestScore = INT_MIN;
    int bestMove = -1;
    int bestMoveOld = -1;
    for (int i : blackPieces) {
        auto legalMoves = GetLegalMoves(i);
        if (legalMoves->size() != 0) {
            for (int move : *legalMoves) {
                int oldP = board[move];
                board[move] = board[i];
                board[i] = 0;
                int score = Minimax(board, 2, false);
                board[i] = board[move];
                board[move] = oldP;
                if (score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score;
                    bestMove = move;
                    bestMoveOld = i;
                }
            }
        }
        delete legalMoves;
    }
    board[bestMove] = board[bestMoveOld];
    board[bestMoveOld] = 0;
    toMove = true;
    std::cout << "Total time spent on legalmoves:" << total.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total legalmoves:" << legalMoveCounter << std::endl;
    legalMoveCounter = 0;
    total -= total;
}

int Board::Minimax(int(&board)[64], int depth, bool isMaximizing) {
    int result = Evaluate(board);
    // An evaluation bigger than 400 means that a king is taken, since
    // the evaluation of all the other pieces is less than 400 in total
    if (depth == 0 || result > 400 || result < -400) {
        return result;
    }

    if (isMaximizing) {
        int bestScore = INT_MIN;
        std::vector<int> blackPieces;
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (board[i] != 0 && GetColor(board[i]) == Color::Black) {
                blackPieces.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i : blackPieces) {
            auto legalMoves = GetLegalMoves(i);
            if (legalMoves->size() != 0) {
                for (int move : *legalMoves) {
                    int oldP = board[move];
                    board[move] = board[i];
                    board[i] = 0;
                    int score = Minimax(board, depth - 1, false);
                    board[i] = board[move];
                    board[move] = oldP;
                    bestScore = std::max(score, bestScore);
                }
            }
            delete legalMoves;
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
    else {
        int bestScore = INT_MAX;
        std::vector<int> whitePieces;
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (board[i] != 0 && GetColor(board[i]) == Color::White) {
                whitePieces.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i : whitePieces) {
            auto legalMoves = GetLegalMoves(i);
            if (legalMoves->size() != 0) {
                for (int move : *legalMoves) {
                    int oldP = board[move];
                    board[move] = board[i];
                    board[i] = 0;
                    int score = Minimax(board, depth - 1, true);
                    board[i] = board[move];
                    board[move] = oldP;
                    bestScore = std::min(score, bestScore);
                }
            }
            delete legalMoves;
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
}

int Board::GetHeldPiece() {
    return heldPiece;
}

const int Board::GetPiece(int index) const{
    return board[index];
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED 
#include <iostream>
#include "graphics.h"

#define VERSION "1.0.0"

int main() {
    std::string fenCode = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
    Graphics g;
    Board b(fenCode);
    g.SetBoard(&b);
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        g.LimitFPS();
        quit = g.InputCheck();
        g.PreRender();
        g.UpdatePieces();
        g.Render();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some general thoughts: don't use `new` in hot code (search), don't use vector or list (prefer c-arrays, you may pre-allocate 6 arrays for the 3 moves you search (6 ply). In general avoid any kind of allocation in hot code. Next, use alpha-beta instead of minimax. Will save you quite a bit.

Comment: @DanielLidström I seem to be getting mixed opinions. Others suggest I only use STL containers. Is the allocation overhead really that big?

Comment: @Offtkp If you are doing it a handful of times in response to a user action, vector is cheap.  If you are doing it once per pixel per frame, or once per lookahead move, or the like, vector is expensive.  In almost every case, `std::list` is a premature pessimization; do not use it unless you are spicing an order of magnitude more often than you are iterating, or your node data is a large number of kilobytes in size, and then still probably don't use it.

Comment: What should happen in the case of a stalemate? ([Yes, stalemate is possible even without the rule that the king can't move into check](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4836/19465).)

Comment: @Offkp you can absolutely use STL containers outside of your hot code. In your hot code you need to drop down a level. The fastest engines use all kinds of tricks to optimze the hot code. To have an idea of what such highly optimized code looks like, see for example https://github.com/abulmo/Dumb/blob/master/src/board.d (D language) or https://github.com/abulmo/hqperft/blob/master/hqperft.c (C language). Those examples might be overkill for you though.

Comment: If there is no check and nothing special about capturing a king, what exactly is the object of the game?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You can capture the king, there's just no checks. So you can play a move that blunders your king also.

Comment: Okay, but then from the perspective of an engine, it's effectively the same game. It would never be correct for the engine to blunder the king; so it just needs to add a trivial check (pun intended) for whether the opposing king has been blundered, and then otherwise calculate normally.

Comment: When writing in C++, there's no reason to use anything but standard library containers, even in "hot" code. Replace "c-arrays" in @Daniel Lidström's original comment with `std::array` (which is nothing more than a standard-library wrapper around a C-style array). The reason you want to avoid `std::vector` is the *dynamic memory allocation*. That problem doesn't plague `std::array`, since it is statically allocated (with the obvious caveat that the size cannot grow dynamically and must be specified at compile time.)

Comment: General advice: If you already think some code is ugly, then very likely it is wrong. Helps a lot ;) (But take with a grain of salt of course)
Check what the stuff you are using actually is. In your case you are using `std::list` which is a linked list. There is no reason to heap allocate that (with new). Just return the list by value and you already get better code and performance. (And as already mentioned by others: Don't use a list, unless you have a good reason to not use a vector)

Answer (score 22):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't `const` qualify POD return values

The code includes this member function within `Board`:

```
const int GetPiece(int index) const;
```

The second `const` is useful and appropriate but the first one is not.  It says that the return value may *not* be altered by the caller which is obviously not correct for plain old data (POD) such as `int` and is probably ignored by the compiler anyway.

### Use C++ limits

The code includes `INT_MIN` which is defined in the old C `<limits.h>` file (which is not `#include`d).  You could add that file, but better would be to use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` from `<limits>`.

### Beware of partially constructed objects

The `Board` constructor is currently this:

```
Board::Board(std::string& fenCode) {
    fen = std::make_unique<FEN>(board, fenCode);
}
```

However, the problem is that `board`, which is passed to the `fen` constructor, is uninitialized.  A more subtle problem is this line:

```
int heldPiece, heldSquare = -1;
```

Due to C++ (and C) syntax, `heldPiece` does not get initialized.  This is one of the major reasons that the guidelines say to always initalize every object (see [ES.20](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-always)).

### Don't pass objects needlessly

The `Evaluate()` and `Minimax()` functions are both member functions of `Board` and so they already have access to data member `board` without explicitly passing it as an argument.

### Prefer `std::array` to plain arrays

In pretty much every way, `std::array` is better than old-style plain C arrays.  So I'd suggest `Board::board` should be `std::array<int, 64>`.  See [SL.con.1](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rsl-arrays) for details.

### Rethink the the use of pointers

The `fen` object is currently owned by the `Board` object as a `std::unique_ptr`, but this isn't really necessary.  Instead, I'd suggest that if you follow the suggestions above, you can make `fen` just a plain `FEN fen;` and the `Board` constructor could look like this:

```
Board::Board(std::string& fenCode) 
    : board{}
    , fen(board, fenCode)
{}
```

### Remove spurious semicolons

The semicolon at the end of both versions of `split` in `fen.cpp` can and should be omitted.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

This code is littered with "magic numbers," that is, unnamed constants such as 55, 62, 64, etc.  Generally it's better to avoid that and give such constants meaningful names.  That way, if anything ever needs to be changed, you won't have to go hunting through the code for all instances of "62" and then trying to determine if this *particular* 62 means that White can castle on the King's side or some other constant that happens to have the same value.

### Evaluate whether an `enum class` is better expressed as a `class`

There are many places in the code where some operation is applied to a piece, but what exactly happens depends on whether it's a knight, bishop, queen, etc.  For that reason, I'd suggest that a better approach may be to create a base `Piece` class and derive `Knight`, `Bishop`, etc.  This would allow you to keep things better organized and reduce a great deal of repetition from the code.  The board could contain pointers to `Piece` and then invoking actions on each would automatically route to the correct routine, whether for evaluating value or determining legal moves.

### Use appropriate data structures

The `heldLegalMoves` is declared to be a `std::list<int>*` but I see no reason it couldn't instead be a much more efficient `std::vector<int>` without the pointer.

### Understand the API

There is a fundamental problem in the way you're trying to draw the board.  The problem is that you've already created a renderer, and then the code attempts to call `SDL_GetWindowSurface()`.  Worse, the return value (which is `nullptr` on my machine) is never checked and it is later freed.  You can *either* have a renderer *or* use `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` but not both.  See https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface

If you do that, `Graphics::InitBoard()` gets simpler, and you can completely remove `boardTexture` and all references to it too:

```
void Graphics::InitBoard() {
    SDL_Rect r{SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE};
    constexpr std::array<std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>, 2> color{{
        {0x61, 0x81, 0x87, 0xFF},   // dark color
        {0xAF, 0xC3, 0xC7, 0xFF}    // light color
    }};
    bool light{true};
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer.get(), 
                color[light][0], color[light][1], color[light][2], color[light][3]
            );
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer.get(), &r); 
            r.x += SQUARE_SIZE;
            light = !light;
        }
        light = !light;
        r.y += SQUARE_SIZE;
        r.x = SCREEN_X;
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer.get(), 0, 0, 0, 255);
}
```

### Think of the user

I was surprised to find out that I could manually move either the white or the black pieces.  Maybe that's intentional?  Being able to reverse or alter a move that my opponent just made might come in handy, but it's unexpected.  Also, I understand this is a work in progress, but I was disappointed that castling (which you did mention) and pawn promotion (which you didn't) aren't yet implemented.  Still, it was kind of fun!

Answer (score 11):

The answers so far are good critiques of the code at a technical level, but optimizing performance of a chess engine is a separate topic. Without aggressive optimizations at the algorithmic level you will quickly run into a combinatorial explosion and very slow performance, and a number of chess-specific techniques have been studied to help with this problem. I haven't done this myself but I have read about it.

One example out of the many techniques available is "alpha-beta pruning" which is a way to stop considering entire trees of moves once it is found that another move is definitely better. This leads to a significant time savings. Read more: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Alpha-Beta#How_it_works

Here are even more links to dig deeper:

- https://www.chessprogramming.org/Getting_Started - a good overview of the concepts involved, even though you've already started down this path
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494721/what-are-some-good-resources-for-writing-a-chess-engine - explanations and links to a lot of other resources
- http://www.frayn.net/beowulf/theory.html - Computer Chess Programming Theory site including explanations and examples of some commonly used algorithms.

Answer (score 9):

Note: this is just a review of `graphics.h` and `graphics.cpp`.

## Apply RAII consistently

I see you used `std::unique_ptr` for `window` and `renderer`, but you did not use smart pointers for `boardTexture` and `piecesTexture`. Use smart pointers for those objects as well. You already have a memory leak here because you never call `SDL_DestroyTexture(piecesTexture)`.

## Be careful about the order of object creation and destruction

There is already a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) when looking at the constructor and destructor of `class Graphics`: the constructor doesn't call any SDL functions directly, but instead calls `Init*()` functions. But the destructor calls `SDL_DestroyTexture()` and `SDL_Quit()` directly. Try to keep things symmetric: if you have an `Init()` function, there should be a corresponding `Exit()`.

But a more subtle issue is the order in which member variables are constructed and destructed. At first glance, the code looks fine, but consider that the constructors of `window` and `renderer` have run before the body of `Graphics::Graphics()` itself. Destructors run in the reverse order of the constructors. So once the `Graphics` object is destructed, first the body of `Graphics::~Graphics()` is run, which calls `SDL_Quit()`, and only then will `SDL_DestroyWindow()` and `SDL_DestroyRenderer()` be called. This order is incorrect, and may cause a crash when the program exits.

There are various ways to solve this issue. If you want to go the RAII way, then create a class that calls `SDL_Init()` in its constructor and `SDL_Quit()` in its destructor, and put a member variable of that type at the start of the definition of `class Graphics`.

## Check if variables need to be initialized

Raw pointers and built-in types like `int` are not initialized (unless they are declared `static`). Especially for pointers, you have to be careful that you don't accidentily dereference an unitialized pointer. Also keep in mind that while you think you might properly initialize them at some point, there might be an error condition occuring before that point which will cause destructors to be called that then might see the unitialized value. For pointer types, avoid raw pointers or ensure they are initialized to `nulltpr`.

For `board`, consider initializing it in the constructor. You can declare a Board`in`main()`before you declare a`Graphics` object.

## Avoid adding unnecessary member variables

There is no need for having `ev`, `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` be a member variables of `class Graphics`. Just declare them as a local variable in `Graphics::InputCheck()`, they are not used elsewhere.

## Use VSync to limit the FPS

Just pass the flag [`SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC) to `SDL_CreateRenderer()`, and SDL will take care of limiting the framerate. It will also prevent tearing.

Answer (score 7):

Use the single responsibility principle.

Your board class stores a board state, evaluates it, runs the AI, provides a scoring function, stores game state, does profiling, supports undo, handles mouse clicks, produces a list of legal moves, and stores pieces being held by the user.

I might have missed something.

Make a class that stores a board state.  Give it a simple API.  Provide methods to modify the board state, possibly as simple as `[[nodiscard]] Board Board::RemovePiece(Location) const` and `[[nodiscard]] Board Board::AddPiece(Location, Piece, Color) const` (note they are const; I made my board Immutable, so editing it returns a brand new board; this isn't as insane as it might sound, as boards are small.)

Then have a function that takes a board and returns valid moves.  It should not be part of the board class, especially in an initial pass.

Similarly, split off a scoring function from the board class, and an class that represents a function taking a scoring function, a valid move generator, and a board, and decides which move to pick.

Your legal moves should be either a vector of moves (not a pointer to it) which involves 1 memeory allocation, or even an array with a size (which involves 0 memory allocations).  Memory allocations cost on the order of 100s of instructions, no point in doing them needlessly; and you'll want to get legal moves really often.

UI interaction should not be part of the above at all.  The user-agent should store the state specific to a user.  It might be a good idea to not care if the user-agent is a human or an AI as far as the Game class is concerned.

The display of the board is, naturally not a concern of the Board class itself.  If you go with the immutable board design above, then the display engine has a copy of its own Board, and you change what you display by saying "SetBoard" into it.

An immutable board class can have some costs, but it does mean you can do things like send a copy of it off to the AI to solve in a thread without worrying about state shared with the UI.

For future use, Board should have ==/!= and a hash function.  That will permit the AI to be working on future multiple future board states on the human turn, and when passed the result of the human turn can prune its tree to look into the one corresponding to the human's move.  (It also helps for stalemate detection and move databases, but move databases should probably be fancier than just equality and hash really)

You are using `int`s a lot as different types of thing.  Toss them into a struct;

```
struct Piece {
  Piece()=default;
  Piece( Type, Color );
  [[nodiscard]] Type Type()const;
  [[nodiscard]] Color Color()const;
  explicit operator bool()const{return bits!=-1;}


  [[nodiscard]] unsigned int GetInternalBits()const{return bits;}
  [[nodiscard]] static Piece MakeFromBits(unsigned int b){
    Piece retval;
    retval.SetInternalBits(b);
    return retval;
  }
private:
  void SetInternalBits(unsigned int b){bits=b;}
  unsigned int bits=-1;
};
```

This makes the Type/Color API more friendly; the bits interface exists, with intentionally awkward names, as you should use it only when you have to.  It is also an immutable type; if you want to change the piece, use `operator=` and assign over it.

Use `[[nodiscard]]` whenever a function's job is to produce its return value; discarding that return value is a sign of a bug.  (You can still force it with a void cast)

Always initialize your class member variables when declared;

```
int halfmoveClock = 0;
```

Use std::array instead of raw C arrays.

Write your AI code reentrantly and functionally.  You have your universe of knowledge (the state), write a function that improves that universe of knowledge by 1 step (in some sense).  Ideally the universe of knowledge can be split up (into multiple branches, say), and you can run the advance code in parallel on multiple branches.

Anticipating the need to multithread, make this code pure and functional -- it takes in some state, and produces some additional objects providing more knowledge.

This lets you (a) unit test the step logic seperately from the main AI, (b) thread off the AI work, (c) do AI work while the user is choosing their move, all of which can give you 100x or more CPU time to do AI work.  Of course, writing a better AI will do more than 100x CPU time improvement, but breaking y our monolithic function down will help you do that as well.

Comment: Good comments, especially about multithreading.  I had considered that as well, but your answer states the issues and solution more clearly and succinctly than I would have done.  Good job!

Comment: I think `Piece MakeFromBits(unsigned int b)` should be `static`.  It doesn't use any class members, and returns a new `Piece`.